# javascript bind method parameters

Tags: javascript

I saw examples of 2 types of bind calls. first kind is:

```
    const book = {
      title: 'Brave New World',
      author: 'Aldous Huxley',
    }

    function summary() {
      console.log(`${this.title} was written by ${this.author}.`)
    }

    const braveNewWorldSummary = summary.bind(book)
```

now "this" in summary is now bond to the "book" object

the second kind is:

```
  function utilizationUpdate(chart, data) {....}

  function utilizationInit(component, btnGroup, data){
        ....
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {....}
        $(btnGroup).on("change", function() {
                    ...
                    fetch('{% url 'api_utilization' fac.fac_id %}?measure=' + measure + '&{{ request.GET.urlencode() }}' )
                    .then(status)
                    .then(json)
                    .then(utilizationUpdate.bind(this, myChart));
                }
            });
        }
```

"chart" in utilizationUpdate() is now bond to myChart.

Why in first bind() example, "this" is not an argument to be passed? but it is specified in the second bind() example?

Comment: first param is this, subsequent are params, have a ponder at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind). Your first example is not the same as second, in the second example, myChart is passed as first param chart in utilizationUpdate

Comment: Thanks. Got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument passed to `bind` is the `this` value and the other arguments are the additional arguments to the function. In the first case, it only sets the `this` value, while in the second case, it sets both the `this` value and the first argument. However, it is likely that the `this` value wasn't truly needed, so `null` could have been passed too.